# Partialview/View Component VS Reactjs components

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, .net-core

Im new to Reactjs.
Can someone explain why I cant just make ajax calls and return partial views or use view components instead of Reactjs? What exactly does react help with? I know about the single page application upsides but still we can do all of those with ajax and partial view. What am I missing here?

Comment: What a wonderful and thoughtful question. Unfortunately this question is not likely addressable on StackOverflow because it would be so subjective it would be called opinion.  Please find a mentor and discuss it with them, you're not wrong in asking this question. It's just the wrong place to do it IMO.

Comment: the server-side framework will do its best to help build reusable components (including UI), at the same time the client-side frameworks also try their best to help build reusable components (usually just UI & related to client-side languages). So here you see an overlap between the 2. However once you combine them, you need to take this over the other (of your choice) or find a way to take the best out of each and combine them (kind of writing your own helpers or designing your own patterns). Finally `reactjs` can live without `asp.net core` and vice-versa.

Comment: I liked your question. You can still use partial views and write a component class works with it. The key method is "Rendering view as string". After that you will be able to generate page forms and other elements by ajax calls. Go ahead and search for it, you will find several solutions on this platform.